# I don't understand the error message for my palindromes function

Tags: python, iteration

Problem: Write a function named palindromes, which takes a string argument and returns True if the string is a palindrome. Palindromes are words which are spelled exactly the same backwards and forwards (ie: racecar). Please also write a main function which asks the user to type in words until they type in a palindrome.

Code:

```
def palindromes(user_word):
    og_word = list(user_word)
    inverse_word = []
    for i in range(len(og_word)-1, -1, -1):
        inverse_word.append(og_word[i])
    if og_word == inverse_word:
        return True

def main():
    while True:
        user_word = input('Please type in a palindrome: ')
        if palindromes(user_word):
            print(f"{user_word} is a palindrome!")
            break
        else:
            print("that wasn't a palindrome")
            
main()
```

[image: This is a picture of my error message.]

Comment: You should probably `return False` in an `else` block or simply, `return og_word == inverse_word`.

Comment: Did you mean: `return og_word == inverse_word`?

Comment: The failure is specific to a given test palindrome. You would improve your question if you gave a record of actually applying the palindrome given in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

your function only returns true when it is a palindrome, but it returns nothing when it is not. That is why the error message says that it compared `None` with `False`. False is the expected result, and None is what your function has returned.

Also, in general, the following coding pattern is not ideal.

```
if condition:
  return True
else:
  return False
```

Well, if the condition is true, you are returning true. If not, you are returning false, which means you can basically write it as

```
return condition
```

So, your function should look like the below:

```
def palindromes(user_word):
    og_word = list(user_word)
    inverse_word = []
    for i in range(len(og_word)-1, -1, -1):
        inverse_word.append(og_word[i])
    return og_word == inverse_word:
```